# Problemas com Php e Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

Emigrei recentemente um código antigo para Mysqli e esta a dar erros.

```
Erro:
Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /var/www/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 10
```

Codigo:

```
function idinfo($id,$value) {
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $id);
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM purchasify_users WHERE usern='$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
return $row[$value];
}
```

Comment: É legal você validar se a sua linha esta retornando alguma coisa. Veja se esta setado com isset() e também a sua quantidade de linhas é maior que 0.

Comment: Não entendi....

Comment: Seu código ta cheio de erros, recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do mysqli para ver as mudanças.

Comment: Concordo com o @Francisco... Precisa rever seu algoritmo. A documentação PHP é incrível para isso...